# Monogame project server issue spawning players

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

I'm making an RPG in monogame c# framework. I have a basic server

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public RPG.CurrencySystem Currency { get; set; }
}

public class GameServer
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenerThread;
    private List<TcpClient> connectedClients;
    private List<Player> players;
    public GameServer()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234); // Port number can be changed
        this.listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.connectedClients = new List<TcpClient>();
        this.players = new List<Player>();
        this.listenerThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started on port 1234");
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening for Clients");

        while (true)
        {
            // blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            this.connectedClients.Add(client);

            // create a thread to handle communication with the connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object clientObj)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)clientObj;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            // Convert the data bytes to a ASCII string and display it
            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + clientMessage);
            // Handle the message and send response if necessary
            // Process the message and send a response back to the client if necessary
            // Example: Echo the received message back to the client
            byte[] reply = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Response: " + clientMessage);
            clientStream.Write(reply, 0, reply.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();

            // Parse the message to extract player information
            if (clientMessage.StartsWith("Player:"))
            {
                string[] parts = clientMessage.Split(',');
                string name = parts[0].Split(':')[1].Trim();
                string positionString = parts[1].Split(':')[1].Trim();
                float x = ParseValue(positionString, "X");
                float y = ParseValue(positionString, "Y");
                // Parse other player data as needed

                // Update player information or add a new player to the list
                Player player = players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
                if (player == null)
                {
                    player = new Player { Name = name };
                    players.Add(player);
                }

                player.Position = new Vector2(x, y);
                // Update other player data as needed
            }

            // Broadcast player positions to all clients
            foreach (Player player in players)
            {
                string positionMessage = $"Player: {player.Name}, Position: {player.Position}";
                BroadcastMessage(positionMessage);
                if (players.Count > 1)
                {
                    BroadcastMessage("Spawnplayer");
                }
            }
           
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
    private void BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        // Send the message to all connected clients
        foreach (TcpClient client in connectedClients)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
    }
    private float ParseValue(string input, string key)
    {
        string keyWithColon = key + ":";
        int startIndex = input.IndexOf(keyWithColon) + keyWithColon.Length;
        int endIndex = input.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1)
        {
            endIndex = input.Length;
        }
        string valueString = input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        float value;
        if (float.TryParse(valueString, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        return 0f; // Return a default value if parsing fails
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameServer server = new GameServer();
    }
}
```

and I have a client in the game

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System.Text;

namespace RPG
{
    public class GameClient
    {
        private TcpClient client;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        private Player player;
        public static List<Player> serverPlayer = new List<Player>();
        XMLManager<Player> PlayerLoader = new XMLManager<Player>();
        public GameClient()
        {
            this.client = new TcpClient();
            this.client.Connect("rpgserv.ddns.net", 1234); // Connect to the server's IP address and port
            this.stream = client.GetStream();
        }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + message);

            data = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            if (response == "Spawnplayer")
            {
                player = new Player();
                serverPlayer.Add(player);
                GamePlayScreen.serverplayers.Add(player);
            }
        }

        private float ParseValue(string input, string key)
        {
            string keyWithColon = key + ":";
            int startIndex = input.IndexOf(keyWithColon) + keyWithColon.Length;
            int endIndex = input.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);
            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                endIndex = input.Length;
            }
            string valueString = input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            float value;
            if (float.TryParse(valueString, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            return 0f; // Return a default value if parsing fails
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
            {
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        public void ReadMessage(string message) 
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + response);

            string[] responseParts = response.Split(new string[] { "Spawnplayer" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string part in responseParts)
            {
                if (part.Contains("Player:"))
                {
                    // Parse player information
                    string[] playerInfo = part.Split(',');
                    string playerName = playerInfo[0].Split(':')[1].Trim();
                    string positionString = playerInfo[1].Split(':')[1].Trim();
                    float x = ParseValue(positionString, "X");
                    float y = ParseValue(positionString, "Y");

                    // Update player information or add a new player to the list
                    Player player = serverPlayer.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == playerName);
                    if (player == null)
                    {
                        player = new Player { Name = playerName };
                        serverPlayer.Add(player);
                        GamePlayScreen.serverplayers.Add(player);
                    }

                    player.pPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                    // Update other player data as needed
                    }
                }
            }
        public void SpawnServerPlayer(string playerName)
        {
            Player serverplayer = new Player();
            serverplayer.Name = playerName;
        }
    }
}
```

my players are loaded via xml this is one of the player files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Player>
  <MoveSpeed>50</MoveSpeed>
  <ClassType>Mage</ClassType>
  <FirstName>Neonzz</FirstName>
  <LastName>
  </LastName>
  <Hardcore>True</Hardcore>
  <SubClass>Fire</SubClass>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Experience>0</Experience>
  <Image>
    <Path>img/SpriteSheetBase</Path>
    <Effects>SpriteSheetEffect</Effects>
  </Image>
</Player>
```

I load this in the GamePlayScreen set to a specific file for testing rather than the player loaded in from the client

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameClient.serverPlayer.Count; i++)
{
    serverplayers[i] = PlayerLoader.Load("Load/Gameplay/Neonzz.xml");
    serverplayers[i].Update(gameTime);
}
```

in my move method for the player I get this for effects
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Image.SpriteSheetEffect was null.

Originally I had the Image saying it was null so I moved the loading logic into update and now I get the SpriteSheetEffect is null I am expecting it to work as it did before adding the logic to spawn server players